# Converting an array of strings into an array of ones and zeros

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
x = ['Green', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green', ...]
```

I want to create a new array y so that:

```
y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...]
```

I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
for n in x:
  if x[n] == 'Red':
    p = 0
  if x[n] == 'Green':
    p = 1
  y.append(p);
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: While iterating directly using `for var in list`, you can directly use `var`. Therefore, you should do `n =='Red'`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary of your desired mappings and then map that to your `list`. This is more flexible if you have a lot of cases.

```
In [8]: x = ['Green', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']

In [9]: d = {'Green':1, 'Red':0}

In [10]: map(d.get, x)
Out[10]: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for v in <sequence>` iterates over *elements* of *< sequence >*.

Use `n` instead of `x[n]` and don't forget to initialize `y` with empty list:

```
y = []
for n in x:
    if n == 'Red':
        p = 0
    if n == 'Green':
        p = 1
    y.append(p)
```

If you have 2 different words (Green and Red) in `x`, then you can simplify this with a list comprehension like

```
y = [1 if == 'Green' else 0 for n in x]
```

or even

```
y = [int(n == 'Green') for n in x]
```

Otherwise create a dictionary and map color names to corresponding numbers e.g

```
numbers = {
    'Red': 0,
    'Green': 1,
    # More colors
}

y = [numbers[n] for n in x]
```